# Grep display both matched and unmatched

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, grep

How can I use grep command to display both matched and unmatched ones ? matched ones should be in red and other things should be in normal color.

Is there a grep option available to do that ?

Comment: Why are you trying to get like this?

Comment: Logs are generated dynamically as the program is running. I need to grep some line which I expect to have errors. If I do grep only the lines matching are printed. I need both matched and unmatched line to understand better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using an alternation pattern where the second pattern matches every line without highlighting anything.

```
grep --color 'pattern\|^' file
```

If you want the whole line colored, not just the matched expression, just modify the regex to match the entire line.

```
grep --color '.*pattern.*\|^' file
```

You can avoid the backslash by using `grep -E` aka `egrep`.  (I believe there could also be prehistoric `grep` implementations which do not support alternation at all, but then they would hardly have the coloring support either.)

Comment: On may `grep` version you do not need to set `--color` option, it's default.

Comment: It is commonly (annoyingly!) set up that way, but explicitly specifying it does no harm and allows the command to work even where this is not the default.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an `awk`

```
cat file
one song
two cars
three houses

awk '/two/ {$0="\033[1;31m"$0"\033[0m"}1' file
one song
two cars
three houses
```

Whit `awk` you can have multiple colors for different finds.

```
awk '/two/ {$0="\033[1;31m"$0"\033[0m"} /hous/ {$0="\033[1;36m"$0"\033[0m"}1' file
one song
two cars
three houses
```

I do use this with `tail` on logs to see what is going on with different colors.

To only color code found word, do:

```
awk '{gsub(/two/,"\033[1;31m&\033[0m")}1' file
```

---

To see what you can use:

```
awk 'BEGIN {for (a=0;a<=1;a++) for (f=30;f<=37;f++) for (b=40;b<=47;b++) print "\033["a";"f";"b"m"a,f,b"\033[m"}'
```

There is even a 256 color version.

Comment: A very good solution usin awk :) Can you please explain the awk command. `awk '/two/ {$0="\033[1;31m"$0"\033[0m"}1' file`

Comment: @KrishnaM The `\033[1;31m` is escape code for setting ansi color in  `awk` Look at this table and you see that `1` is bold and `31` is red foreground etc: http://pueblo.sourceforge.net/doc/manual/ansi_color_codes.html