# grep: highlight only first match of each line when using --color

Tags: regex, linux, grep, highlight

When I make `grep` highlight the matches like this:

```
echo hello hello | grep --color "hello"
```

I get highlighted **all matches** in the line, which in the above case is all the line:

> **hello hello**

How can I get highlighted only the **first ocurrence**:

> **hello** hello

I suppose I can do it with a complex regex but I wonder if there a simpler solution.

Comment: `echo 'hello hello' | grep --color "^hello"` will work for your example but can there be other characters before first `hello`?

Comment: Strange close vote. This is definitely not off-topic due to use of `grep/sed/awk`

Comment: Using these tools interactively isn't really scripting.

Comment: Coloring of matched text can be used in any script and there are tons of answers on SO that deal with interactive tools

Comment: **can** being the operative word. This isn't..

Comment: Let that be decided by OP

Comment: No, let that be decided by the rules. ;)

Comment: And so called *rules* are subject to (mis)interpretation :)

Comment: Evident in [example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24908076/548225) and [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29003924/548225)

Comment: There is no way to get grep to only color the first match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be easily done using `sed`:

```bash
sed 's/hello/\x1b[31m&\x1b[0m/' file
```

This will only color first match of `hello` word in each line. In replacement we are putting matched word back using `&` surrounded with escape code for color red.

Similarly you can do this in `awk` as well:

```bash
awk '{sub(/hello/, "\x1b[31m&\x1b[0m")} 1' file
```